# Does PyMySQL support SELECT...FOR UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

PyMySQL, a python package to access MySQL database, seems not support SELECT ... FOR UPDATE.

In the code below, I used SELECT...FOR UPDATE to read some_table in function f(), used UPDATE to modify the table in g(), and spawned 50 threads for each function.

I expected deadlock to happen since SELECT...FOR UPDATE should block the threads spawned by g. But actually no deadlock happened. Can some one explain why?

```
from threading import Thread
import pymysql

def f():
    db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "tester","pwd", "testDB")
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table FOR UPDATE"
    try:
        cur.execute(sql)
    except:
        print("Exception in select")

def g():
    db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "tester", "pwd","testDB")
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "UPDATE some_table SET val=20 WHERE id=2"
    try:
       cur.execute(sql)
       db.commit()
    except:
       print("Exception in update")
       db.rollback()

for _ in range(50):
    Thread(target=f, args=()).start()
    Thread(target=g, args=()).start()
```

I am using Python 3.4 and PyMySQL 0.6.6. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PyMySQL does support **[SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#:%7E:text=SELECT%20...%20FOR%20UPDATE)**

But you need start the transaction using `connection.begin()`

Here's an example:

```py
connection= pymysql.connect("localhost", "tester", "pwd","testDB")
connection.begin()
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table FOR UPDATE")
```

Table/row (depending upon your select query) is now in ***locked*** state. Only the current connection can make changes.

To ***release the lock***. You can,

1. ***commit*** the changes (if any)

```py
connection.commit()
```

2. ***close*** the connection

```py
connection.close()
```